# Relacionar de tabelas com CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tem duas tabelas no banco de dados, **posts** e **comments** e quero relacioná-las.

Acho que tenho que criar uma chave estrangeira na tabela *comments* em um campo que guarde o título ou o id da tabela *posts*, assim saberei de qual postagem aquele comentário é.

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_title` 
FOREIGN KEY (`title_id`)  REFERENCES `posts` (`title`);
```

Mas tenho dúvidas por causa das convenções do CakePHP.

Posso usar o campo **id** da tabela *posts*, como no código a seguir, ou devo usar o campo *title* como tentei fazer no código acima?

```
ALTER TABLE `comments` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) 
REFERENCES `posts` (`id`);
```

Tenho dúvida quanto a esse índice *fk_title* também. Para quê serve?

**Uma vez que eu tenha criado o campo *post_id* na tabela *comments* e feito o relacionamento abaixo:**

```
class Post extends AppModel {
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment'
    )
);
}
```

Tenho ainda que fazer o ALTER TABLE no SQL do MYSQL?

Tenho que fazer esse mesmo processo do *$hasMany* dentro da *class Comment* (do model Comment.php criado para a tabela "comments")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deve referenciar a tabela de `posts` pelo título pelo simples fato de que mais de um post pode ter o mesmo título, causando uma inconsistência no seu modelo de dados.

Mesmo que você defina o título como `UNIQUE`, ainda assim fica estranho. O ideal é que tanto a tabela de posts quanto a de comentários possuam id's, e as referências entre as tabelas sejam feitas por meio dos id's.

Seu relacionamento deveria ser assim:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment'
        )
    );
}
```

PS: Quando ao `fk_title`, trata-se da referência que a tabela de posts faz com a de comentário, no modelo proposto na sua pergunta.

Comment: Poderia olhar minha edição? Desde já agradeço pela resposta. No caso dentro do Model Post tenho que usar o $hasMany para informar que a tabela posts tem chave estrangeira na tabela comments?

Comment: Na class "Comment" referente  à tabela "Comments" faço a mesma coisa?

Comment: Se a classe Post "possui muitos" comentários, evidentemente a classe Comment "pertence a" (`belongsTo`) classe Post (e não "possui muitos" Post's, como você perguntou).

Comment: Quanto a alterar seu modelo, não sei responder pois não trabalho com CakePHP. Mas sei que colocar os relacionamentos em ambas as models e alterar a chave estrangeira já corrige o que havia de errado no seu modelo.

Comment: Valeu! Muito útil!

Comment: Se deu certo, não esqueça de validar a resposta. :)

Comment: Estudei mais relacionamentos, não foi bem a resposta específica para o que eu queria concluir, mas  me ajudou a encontrar novas soluções, obrigado.